# Root IMAP folder in MS Exchange similar to ALL MAIL folder in gmail IMAP

Tags: gmail, exchange-server, imap

Is there a way to connect to an IMAP folder in ms exchange mail server via which I can access all mails inside the mailbox. I mean all mails including the INBOX, Sent Mails and other folder which are in same hierarchy as Inbox folder.

I'm looking for something similar to [Gmail]/All Mail folder in gmail IMAP. This folder gives me access to all mails present in all folders at once.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I'm aware of to ask IMAP to project a view of the entire mailbox with Exchange.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably have to figure out some other way to approach the problem.